# 108 edits, yet no Strunk & White badge

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I checked the [`Users > Editor > All`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) tab, and learnt that I have made 108 edits so far. "Strunk & White" badge is given after 80 edits, but I did not receive it. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy/pasting my reply from [Super User-](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2176/889-edits-yet-no-copy-editor-badge/2177#2177)

There are.. [certain requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) which count for "edits"

> - does not include edits to your own posts
> - does not include edits to tags
> - community-wiki posts are eligible
> - tag wiki posts are eligible
> - only edits to title and body count towards the S&W/Copy Editor badges

There is a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges) for tracking edit progress ( thanks to [Lord Torgamus/Popular Demand for composing](https://superuser.com/users/6442/lord-torgamus?tab=accounts) the query.

The query mentions that you still need to do about ~40<sup>*****</sup> more edits to get the badge.

<sup>***** *although the query mentions you need 79 edits, considering that the SEDE relies on datadumps which are out of date and need not necessarily hold the required information, I removed 30 more edits, giving an approximate number. The actual required number might be higher/lower*</sup>

Comment: Hi Sathya, I was suddenly given the Strunk & White badge a minute ago. Isn't that strange?

Comment: The badges are given as part of a scheduled job @MehperC. Palavuzlar, you might have crossed the threshold earlier in the day, and awarded right away :)